How to Set the Correct Endpoint URL for a Push Subscription in Google Cloud?
I recently encountered an issue with my Google Cloud Function not being invoked after deleting the default Pub/Sub subscription.
To troubleshoot, I manually created a new push subscription using the following endpoint URL format:
https://region-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/function-name
However, the function is still not being triggered as expected. I suspect there might be an issue with the push endpoint configuration in the manually created subscription.
Could anyone guide me on what value should be set for the endpoint URL when creating a push subscription? Is there any additional configuration required to ensure the function is invoked properly?
Thank you in advance!

I don't know what a "default pub/sub subscription" is supposed to be, but authentication might be turned on for the function, in which case you'll need to configure that for the push subscription as well (and confirm that the pubsub agent SA has rights to trigger the function).

HI @SUDHARSHAN D, If you found that below information helpful please do upvote or accept as per Stack Overflow guidelines , helping more Stack contributors with their research

Hi @SouravDutta, Thank you for your message and for providing the information. I appreciate your efforts in assisting me. However, I have tried the steps mentioned, and unfortunately, they did not resolve my issue.

Endpoint URL Format for Cloud Function should be in proper format like Region where cloud function is deployed , your project I'd and cloud function name . you can follow this doc  and also @ somethingsomething already mentioned authentication might be turned on for the function, in which case you'll need to configure that for the push subscription as well (and confirm that the pubsub agent SA has rights to trigger the function) .
